# Insert a blank row into a csv file when writing using php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv, row

I am writing a csv file using "fputcsv" in codeignitor. 
I have got two tables in array form and they do get written in the csv file.

Now I want to insert some blank rows in the csv file as a separator between two tables.

```
$this->load->helper('download');

$blanks = array("\t","\t","\t","\t");

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ($writedata as $fields) { //table one
fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
foreach ($blanks as $fields) { //blank space insertion try
fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
}

foreach ($table2 as $fields) { //table two
fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
$data = file_get_contents('php://output');
$name = 'data.csv';
```

Tried different version of blank and tried inserting it but didn't work.

Language - PHP
Framework  - Codeignitor

Comment: `fputcsv($fp, [])`?

Comment: Yes this works smoothly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked. 
Please excuse the indentation.
With this I can always customize how i want the blank lines.

```
$this->load->helper('download');

$blanks = array();
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
    {
    array_push($blanks,array("\t","\t","\t","\t");
    }

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ($writedata as $fields) {
   fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

foreach ($blanks as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

foreach ($table2 as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
$data = file_get_contents('php://output');
$name = 'data.csv';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<?php

$this->load->helper('download');

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ($writedata as $fields) { //table one
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
    fput($fp, PHP_EOL);
}

foreach ($table2 as $fields) { //table two
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
$data = file_get_contents('php://output');
$name = 'data.csv';
```

or

```
$this->load->helper('download');

$blanks = array("\t","\t","\t","\t");

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ($writedata as $fields) { //table one
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
    fputcsv($fp, $blanks);
}

foreach ($table2 as $fields) { //table two
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
$data = file_get_contents('php://output');
$name = 'data.csv';
```